# Jwplayer audio/video & Fetch as Google

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer, audio-streaming, google-search-console

I'm trying to render webpages using Fetch as Google. Our media pages use jwplayer 7. I use different streaming formats (hls, progressive download, ...) but no files are correctly rendererd in Desktop mode using the 'Fetch as Google' option (Google Webmaster). 
Googlebot can fetch all important files (in both desktop/mobile mode)

Google shows the player with error message, depending on the type of streaming / file used and differently for desktop/mobile):

- [hls / live mp4] (desktop / mobile) error playing file: unknown playback error
- [mp3] (desktop) error loading player: no playable sources found
- [mp3] (mobile) works!
- [hls / m4a] (mobile) works!
- [hls / m4a] (desktop) error playing file: unknown playback error
- [hls / mp4] (mobile) works!
- [hls / mp4] (desktop) error playing file: unknown playback error

Do you know any reason for different streaming media support using Fetch as Google?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:** The issue occurs when 'autostart' is set to 'true'. For this reason the mobile render works good: on mobile device our site sets 'autostart' to 'false'. JwPlayer works good with Fetch as Google only with 'autostart: false'.

Comment: What JW player licence/edition are you using? HLS playback on desktop requires minimum Premium edition.

Comment: a premium license, of course. But all works good on users computer, the problem occurs only with the Fetch as Google

Comment: Found it! This issue occurs when 'autostart' is set to 'true'. For this reason the mobile render works good: autostart is false on mobile. Now I update my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the appropriate schema.org tags so Googlebot can render the video?

http://schema.org/docs/gs.html